# How does exit(EXITT_FAILURE) work in both c and c++?

Tags: c++

I used exit(EXIT_FAILURE) in a precise function which is not the main one, but after its execution nothing is executed in the main function.
I really wanna know why ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you asking why calling `exit` caused your program to... exit? That's what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand how `exit` works it helps to understand how program termination upon returning from `main` works.

When the program returns from `main` it returns to a piece of helper code in the C or C++ runtime. That piece performs some cleanup and then calls the [`_exit`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/_exit.html) system call with the return value of `main`. The kernel will stop execution of the process at that point.

The [`exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) function has similar behavior, it performs the same cleanup as the helper code from the C and C++ runtime does when returned from main, then calls the `_exit` system call. It's this last call to the `_exit` system call that prevents execution of anything else (in `main` or otherwise) after calling of `exit`.